# Silverlight 2 ArgumentException

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-2.0

I have a silverlight 2 app that has an ObservableCollection of a class from a separate assem/lib. When I set my ListBox.ItemsSource on that collection, and run it, I get the error code:

> 4004 "System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range."

Here is part of the code:

```
public partial class Page : UserControl
{
    ObservableCollection<Some.Lib.Owner> ooc;

    public Page()
    {
        
        ooc = new ObservableCollection<Some.Lib.Owner>();
        Some.Lib.Owner o1 = new Some.Lib.Owner() { FirstName = "test1" };
        Some.Lib.Owner o2 = new Some.Lib.Owner() { FirstName = "test2" };
        Some.Lib.Owner o3 = new Some.Lib.Owner() { FirstName = "test3" };
        ooc.Add(o1);
        ooc.Add(o2);
        ooc.Add(o3);

        InitializeComponent();
        lb1.ItemsSource = ooc;
    }
}
```

But when I create the Owner class within this same project, everything works fine.
Is there some security things going on behind the scenes? Also, I'm using the generate a html page option and not the aspx option, when I created this Silverlight 2 app.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use a standard class library or a "Silverlight Class Library"?

Because Silverlight 2 uses a subset of the CLR it cannot access standard class libraries that were compiled using the full CLR.  To use an external assembly you must create it as a "Silverlight Class Library".  This will create a project that only includes the namespaces available to Silverlight and will allow you to reference the assembly within your Silverlight project.

Check out the MSDN article [".NET Framework Class Library for Silverlight"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838194(VS.95).aspx) for more info.

Comment: Yeah, I created it as a Silverlight Class Library. After countless hours searching "The Google", I just gave up. Everything is in one project now.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you're not handling a failure in SubmittedChanges(). See http://www.scottleckie.com/2010/04/code-4004-unhandled-error-in-silverlight-application/ for more info

Answer (score 0):

> Everything is in one project now.

Yes, but not like you just did it, instead, share, *link to* the file(s).

For this an old *jedi mind trick* of Silverlight when there is a need to share common `entity` code between the app and the service. This is done when the library could not be brought in due to the differences in .Net/CLR.

The trick is to include the file as a *link* into the other project. Here is how

1. In the target (Silverlight project) folder which needs the code file, right click and select `Add` then `Existing Item...` or `shift` `alt` `A`.
2. Browse to the location of the origins file(s) found and select the/those file(s).
3. Once the item(s) have been selected, then on the `Add` button select the drop down arrow.
4. Select `Add as link` to add the file(s) as a link into the folder.

[image]

Once done, there is only one copy, but built in two different places.

That will give access to the file *as if* the file was actually within the project's  folder, but the file physically resides elsewhere...and avoids CLR issues.